# When I send 'GET' request, returning '404 page not found' in Golang

Tags: rest, go, http

I'm new on Golang. I try to write an API server with Golang without any HTTP framework(echo, gin, etc.). I wrote 'post' endpoint but my 'get' endpoint not respond. I tried to write another get endpoint named 'ping' and it was working. My curl

```bash
curl --location 'http://localhost:8080/users/45254424-5be1-487d-9131-bad3b2f7791c'
```

My handler

```golang
func (u UserHandler) GetById(writer http.ResponseWriter, request *http.Request) {
    id := strings.TrimPrefix(request.URL.Path, "/users/")
    user := u.userService.GetById(uuid.Must(uuid.Parse(id)))
    writer.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
    json.NewEncoder(writer).Encode(user)
}
```

My main method

```golang
postgresConnection := db.NewDb()
userRepository := repository.NewUserRepository(postgresConnection)
userService := service.NewUserService(userRepository)
userHandler := handlers.NewUserHandler(userService)

mux := http.NewServeMux()
mux.HandleFunc("/users", func(writer http.ResponseWriter, request *http.Request) {
    if request.Method == "POST" {
        userHandler.Create(writer, request)
    } else {
        http.Error(writer, "Invalid request method", http.StatusMethodNotAllowed)
    }
})
mux.HandleFunc("/users/:id", func(writer http.ResponseWriter, request *http.Request) {
    if request.Method == "GET" {
        userHandler.GetById(writer, request)
    } else {
        http.Error(writer, "Invalid request method", http.StatusMethodNotAllowed)
    }
})
mux.HandleFunc("/ping", PingHandler)

err := http.ListenAndServe(":8080", mux)
log.Fatal(err)
```

Comment: The use path `"/users/"` in the second call to mux.HandleFunc.  See the mux documentation for a description of how paths are  matched.

Comment: @CeriseLimón thanks i catched the request in debug mode but returning err (runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
goroutine 6 [running]:). I will read the documentation of mux.

Comment: The pattern `"/users/:id"` matches the exact path  `/users/:id`.  The `:id` has no special meaning in the pattern.  Which line of code in the question corresponds to the file name and line number in the panic stack trace?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- When registering the handler, change the patterns argument `/users/:id` to `/users/`.

```golang
mux.HandleFunc("/users/", func(writer http.ResponseWriter, request *http.Request) {
     id := strings.TrimPrefix(request.URL.Path, "/users/")

     ...
})
```

> **Note**: There are numerous third-party libraries available to assist you in writing a more readable and efficient HTTP server.
>
> Examples
>
> - [Gin](https://gin-gonic.com)
> - [Fiber](https://docs.gofiber.io)